# symfony2 ("There is no "cssrewrite" filter.") in "base.html.twig"

Tags: php, symfony

Small question. I'm learning the symfony2 framework and I get this error

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("There is no "cssrewrite" filter.") in "base.html.twig".

Do I have to manually activate it somewhere or went there something wrong with the installation processes (running it on windows). Can someone point me in the right direction?

twig:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
        '@blogBundle/Resources/public/css/costom.css'
            %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
            {% endstylesheets%}
        {% endblock %}
    framework:
        secret: xxxxxxxxxx
        router:        { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
        templating:    { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```

config.yml file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@blogBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: Can you post your template code?

Comment: Please post the template code and the config.yml file

Comment: The config.yml from app/config/config.yml please

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 okay thanks

Comment: Where is your assetic configuration in this config.yml ?? I don't see it .... Maybe were you in the bad config.yml ?

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 noo this is app/config/config.yml . Maybe I messed up the installation of the bundles?

Comment: Look at [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#filters), I don't see your assetic entry in config.yml and [this one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html)

Comment: Have you seen the notice that says: "When using the cssrewrite filter, don't refer to your CSS files using the \@AppBundle syntax." Maybe your \@blogBundle causes the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Symfony3, assetic is not included by default, you must install it using composer (which I suspect you did). But you also need to add it to your config.yml like this:

```
assetic:
    debug: "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: "%kernel.debug%"
    bundles: []
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```